# Factoring sets with common variables

Tags: notation

Is there a way to elegantly factor a set? For example, I have the following set:

$$A = \{ax,ay,az,bx,by,bz \}$$

Can we write this as:

$$A = \{a(x,y,z),b(x,y,z) \}$$
Or is there a more elegant way of writing this?

Comment: What does mean "factoring a set"?

Comment: If you incline: $\{a,b\} \cdot \{x,y,z\}$. However it is every context specific. I would explain it in text anyway...